# Mysql Auto-incremento condicionado a uma coluna da tabela

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Olá,

Estou tentando criar uma tabela de veículos que fique da seguinte maneira com php e mysql:

```
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
| id | nome do veiculo | marca | codigo |
| 1  | Gol             | VW    | 1      |
| 2  | Golf            | VW    | 2      |
| 3  | Fox             | VW    | 3      |
| 4  | Palio           | Fiat  | 1      |
| 5  | Argo            | Fiat  | 2      |
+----+-----------------+-------+--------+
```

Onde id tem o auto incremento e o código seria adicionado conforme o número de veículo da marca.

Ex: Se entrasse mais um carro da vw ele receberia id 6 e o código 4. Caso fosse fiat receberia o id 6 só que o código 3.

Eu tentei fazer o valor do código da seguinte maneira:

$selveiculos = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id FROM veiculos where marca='$marca'");
        $codveiculo = 1 + mysqli_num_rows($selveiculos);

Onde eu verifico a quantidade de veículos de uma marca X e faço o código ser o número retornado.

Meu problema é que eu estou pegando os dados dos veículos com uma função $.ajax que já passa direto para esse código php para inserir no banco. Então o que está acontecendo é de criar códigos iguais para veículos de da mesma marca.

Teria como criar o id com auto-incremento e o código com um auto-incremento mas relacionando com a marca?

Alguma sugestão para resolver isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Acho que é melhor separar as informaçõe em duas tabelas, `veiculo` teria `id`, `nome` e `id_marca` e `marca` teria `id` e `nome_marca` ou `marca`

Comment: Desta maneira o problema continuaria pois o o id seria auto-incremento e ficaria com valores 1,2,3,4,5.. e não a quantidade de veículos por por marca. Exemplo: Começou inserindo 10 carros da fiat, então o id iria de 1 até 10. Ai começa adicionar carro da vw , neste caso o id começaria do 11 e não do 1 como eu gostaria

Answer (score 1):

Você não poderá ter um campo AUTOINCREMENT com dois valores iguais. Uma solução seria uma query para pegar o próximo id daquela marca

```
SELECT MAX(codigo)+1 AS proximo_codigo WHERE marca = :IDMARCA
```